# Problem with using regular expression in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I have a column with name "data-description" which has entries like

```
Mumbai,Maharastra,India
London,London, Britain
Chandigarh,Haryana,India
Lahore, Punjab, Non-India
```

Each line describes the value of one data-description column.

Now I need to update another table which will have three columns which will have

```
<City> => <Citycode>   ---> Every City 
<Statename> => <Statename>
<Country>  => <Country>
```

I have a table where a mapping between City and City-Code is made. Now I need to make another table with the three columsn Citycode, Statename, Country

How do I do this with a couple of SQl statements and without using any PL/SQL?

Also, The order may not be the same in rows. Like some rows have order City,State,County. Others may have the order State,Country,City.

Comment: So essentially you want to extract the value from this single column into 3 columns which you can then proceed to use in your query, e.g to JOIN to another table with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm#i1239858) to extract information from your source column:

```
SQL>  WITH my_data AS (
  2      SELECT 'Mumbai,Maharastra,India' d FROM dual
  3      UNION ALL SELECT 'London,London, Britain' d FROM dual
  4      UNION ALL SELECT 'Chandigarh,Haryana,India' d FROM dual
  5      UNION ALL SELECT 'Lahore, Punjab, Non-India' d FROM dual
  6   )
  7   SELECT regexp_substr(d, '[^, ]+', 1, 1) City,
  8          regexp_substr(d, '[^, ]+', 1, 2) Statename,
  9          regexp_substr(d, '[^, ]+', 1, 3) Country
 10     FROM my_data;

CITY                      STATENAME                 COUNTRY
------------------------- ------------------------- -------------------------
Mumbai                    Maharastra                India
London                    London                    Britain
Chandigarh                Haryana                   India
Lahore                    Punjab                    Non-India
```

Comment: If they are not in the same order. Like some of them are in the order Maharastra, Mumbai, India